# Is there any issue in making threads in a java threadpool as daemon threads

Tags: java, threadpool

I am starting a java thread pool [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)  (with a core pool size)  inside a `Weblogic server (WLS)`. To normally shutdown the pool i need to call `shutdown()` on this pool. But for reasons beyond my control I am not able to add any Application life cycle listener in this WLS , which means I dont have any shutdown hook to call this method.
So I am thinking to make the threads in pool as daemon threads , so that `WLS JVM` will not wait for these threads to finish when it is shutting down. Else JVM will not normally shutdown as core threads in pool are always running.

Is there any disadvantage of making threads in thread pool as daemon.  I understand about daemon threads, when JVM exits, these threads will never be normally cleaned up and any thing running will not finish normally. This issue is only during shutdown stage.

Is there any other issue in making threads daemon in a thread pool ?  (or a better way)

Comment: Issues related to deamon threads will be related to what these threads actually do. Only you know what tasks those threads execute.

Comment: [A few ideas about pros and cons of daemon threads](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[java]%20why%20use%20daemon%20threads)

Comment: Have you looked at [Work Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/config_wls/self_tuned.html)

Comment: @mprabhat  thanks. I need a thread pool with some very specific custom functionalities. So Work Managers cannot be used.

Comment: Have a look at the last example [here](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/) assuming you haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are in an application container, you may want to use Work Managers as @mprabhat suggests. But if you truly need threads that are under your control, you can still shut them down. WebLogic implements it's Application life cycle notification via shutdown hooks. And that mechanism is still available to you. You can use [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) to register one. Don't forget that to do your work quickly. WebLogic has a timeout, so the shutdown sequence is basically:

1. Shutdown requested (either by System.exit() or a signal sent to the JVM process).
2. Your shutdown hooks and WebLogic's shutdown hooks execute.
3. After some timeout (5-10 sec I think) one of WebLogic's shutdown hooks calls System.halt().
4. The JVM terminates regardless of whether shutdown hooks have completed.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link and I suggested Use java 7 thread concurrently

http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/

enjoy